# Why root block render automatically content in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, magento2.2.2, containers

In **Magento 1** we have the possibility the add a block in a **root** block so it will not be displayed because **root** is not a `core/text_list` block type **(structural block)**, it doesn't render automatically the content block without calling it in **phtml** like : `getChildHtml()`, `getBlockHtml()`. So we need to call it in phtml to render it.

Example:

**local.xml**

```
<catalog_product_view>
   <reference name="root">
      <block type="core/template" name="block.name" template="page/html/file1.phtml"/>
   </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Here we need to call that block to render it like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('block.name'); ?>
```

But in **Magento 2** the `root` container render automatically the root block why ?

I need like Magento 1, declare my block in `xml`, this `xml` doesn't render it, and it's me who must call it where i want.

I don't know if there is an equivalent of `root` in **Magento 2**

**Example:**

```
<referenceContainer name="root">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="block.name" template="Magento_Theme::page/html/file1.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your `block` without `<referenceContainer>` in your layout file (i.e `catalog_product_view`, `checkout_cart_index`) under `<body>` tag then you can call in your `.phtml` file with `echo $block->getBlockHtml('some.name');`

Comment: So without a container, the block is displayed in root right ? And do you know if it is possible to declare a layout handle in `default.xml` like `M1`, in `local.xml` we declare a layout handle then we include our block that it will be displayed in that layout handle, it's really useful I don't know why they removed it in `M2` !

Comment: If you want to put some block on all page(i.e footer link, top link) then you can put in `default.xml` @Prince

Comment: Yes I know this but in `Magento 2` we are obliged to add each block in each layout handle xml, we can't put all changes in one xml like `local.xml` in `Magento1`